# Could Static Electricity interfere with HP Pavilion Active Pen?

Tags: stylus

My HP Active Pen worked for two months with my new HP Pavilion x360.  They are sold together.  Then it stopped.  I changed batteries and it worked again, for a day or two.  Then it stopped.  Changed batteries again, but it would not work.  Put it aside a few days, now it works again.  I am wondering if placing it on the end table by the couch with my cell phone, my cell phone QI charger, or possible drips from drinking glasses could have short-circuited it.  Also, there is a lot of static in the house this year,  Every time I pet the cat, he backs up from the static.  Could that interfere with how the pen works?  This pen does not use bluetooth, only a single AAAA battery.
Can anyone explain this to me?